# Mountain Lion Secure Transport SSLHandshake returns errDecryptionFail after Change Cipher Spec

Tags: macos, ssl

On Mountain Lion, running some SSL code that works on Leopard - using the native Secure Transport Framework - the server-side SSLHandshake call fails with errDecryptionFail.

Looking at a wireshark trace, the handshake proceeds normally until the client sents a Change Cipher Spec and Encrypted Handshake Message. In response the server closes the connection and returns errDecryptionFail.

The apple documentation states:

"errSSLDecryptionFail    –9845
Decryption failed. Among other causes, this may be caused by invalid data coming from the remote host, a damaged crypto key, or insufficient permission to use a key that is stored in the keychain."

Has anyone seen similar behaviour or could shed some light on what the "other causes" might be?

Thanks,

Richard.